# Rails — How do I see old and new model values from an after_save callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Let's say I have the following models:

```
class V < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :p
  after_save :after_save_v
  ...
end

class P < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vs
  # Has an attribute called "score" (defined in the DB table)
  ...
end
```

Creating a V increases `v.p.score` by 1.
**Now in my `after_save_v`, I would like to track the old value of `p.score`. How can I do this?**

Using a p.score_was does not work.

```
class V < ActiveRecord::Base
  def after_save_v
    puts p.score_was # => 1
    puts p.score # => 1
  end
end
```

What am I missing here? Or is this something that is not possible from the after_save callback?

Comment: As you are checking old value in `after_save` callback the value was already updated so it returns the same value. Once try getting that value `before_save` into some variable and use that variable  according your requirement

Answer (score 2):

In `after_save`, if you use the [`changes`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveModel/Dirty/changes) method, it returns the hash of all the changes on your object. You can specify which attribute's changes you need. This will be an array. [old-value, new-value]

In your Example, it can be `self.p.changes["score"]`. This returns an array `[0, 1]`, where `0` is the old value, and `1` is the new value